# Spline fitting - Douglas-Peucker algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, haskell, bezier, spline

I am planning on using the Douglas-Peucker algorithm for point reduction (unless someone knows of a better example).  The data is 1D and the curve being constructed is 2D

Give a reduced hull of points I need a spline that will travel through all the points (I think Lagrange interpolation does this)

The main objective is to solve the tangent handles on something like a hermite curve so that the spline matches the original data curve as closely as possible.

Does anyone know of a an approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: Is there a reason that this question is tagged with both C++ and Haskell?

Comment: Solutions, in terms of libraries or example code for either C++ or Haskell would be ideal for this problem.  I will fix 'splice'  to spline - just a typo.

Comment: You can define an objective function and solve it as a non-linear optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you solve this? A spline that travels through your points is easily constructed as a Catmull-Rom spline (which map to Bezier curves, but represent the interpolation differently).

Comment: Is it possible to break tangents with the Catmull-Rom? Also is converting back to a 1D parameter to read values difficult?  I'm open to a variety of approaches, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution yet.

Comment: Catmull-Rom has a nice property where the tangent at point P is equal to the line {P-1, P+1}, so if you do it correctly, the tangents should all look just fine.